# Send a list from Erlang to Java using JInterface

Tags: java, concurrency, erlang, jinterface

I'm writing a program requiring communication between Java and Erlang using JInterface.
I've a problem with receiving a list from an Erlang process - somehow the object I get in Java is not a OtpErlangList but OtpErlangString and if I try to cast the received object to OtpErlangList, I get a cast exception. I've tried decoding the string, but it seems not to be the case.

It seems to me rather odd not be able to send a list from Erlang to Java, could you please take a look if I'm not making any basic mistake?

Java fragment:

```
OtpErlangObject erlangObject = mailbox.receive();
OtpErlangList erlangList = (OtpErlangList) erlangObject;
System.out.println(erlangList.toString());
```

Erlang fragment:

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4],
JavaPid ! List
```

I'm omitting the rest of the code as I believe these are the lines where the problem is - I've tried it with other classses and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Jinterface](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/jinterface/jinterface_users_guide.html) documentations:

> Lists in Erlang are also used to describe sequences of **printable characters** (strings). A convenience class `OtpErlangString` is provided to represent Erlang strings.

### Getting String

For getting a string of printable characters in Java side, you should use `stringValue()` method which converts a list of integers into a Unicode string and returns a `java.lang.String` object.

**Erlang side:**

```
List = "hey" = [$h, $e, $y] = [104, 101, 121],
JavaPid ! List
```

**Java side:**

```
OtpErlangObject erlangObject = mailbox.receive();
OtpErlangList erlangList = (OtpErlangList) erlangObject;
System.out.println(erlangList.stringValue());
```

### Getting Array

For getting a list of elements in Java side, you should use `elements()` method which returns an array containing all of the list's elements. This way each element of array is an object of type `OtpErlangObject`.

**Erlang side:**

```
List = [1, 2, 3, 4],
JavaPid ! List
```

**Java side:**

```
OtpErlangObject erlangObject = mailbox.receive();
OtpErlangList erlangList = (OtpErlangList) erlangObject;    
for(OtpErlangObject element : erlangList.elements()) {
    // do something with element
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In erlang, a string is just an array of small integer numbers. For example in erlang shell,

```
1> A = "abcdefgh".
"abcdefgh"
2> A ++ [1024].
[97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,1024]
3> A ++ [105].
"abcdefghi"
```

So my guess is that this kind of list is always interpreted as string on Java side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to J.J. Hakala example, the answer is that if you send a list containing only integers that could be interpreted as ASCII codes, Java does exactly so - interpret it as an array of ASCII codes aka string:

```
            OtpErlangObject erlangObject = mailbox.receive();

            if (erlangObject instanceof OtpErlangString) {
                OtpErlangString string = (OtpErlangString) erlangObject;
                for(char c: string.stringValue().toCharArray()) {
                    int num = (int) c;
                    System.out.println(num);
                }
            }
```